# How to Match two APIs to update one API dataset using Python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, put

I want to be able to GET information from API 1 and match it with API 2 and be able to update API 2's information with API 1. I am trying to figure out the most efficient/automated  way to accomplish this as it also needs to be updated at a interval of every 10 minutes

I can query and get the results from API 1 this is my code and what my code looks like.

```
import json
import requests

myToken = '52c32f6588004cb3ab33b0ff320b8e4f'
myUrl = 'https://api1.com/api/v1/devices.json'
head = {'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(myToken)}
response = requests.get(myUrl, headers=head)
r = json.loads(response.content)
r
```

The payload looks like this from API 1

```
{ "device" : {
"id": 153,
"battery_status" : 61,
"serial_no": "5QBYGKUI05",
"location_lat": "-45.948917",
"location_lng": "29.832179",
"location_address": "800 Laurel Rd, Lansdale, PA 192522,USA"}
}
```

I want to be able to take this information and match by "serial_no" and update all the other pieces of information for the corresponding device in API 2

I query the data for API 2 and this is what my code looks like

```
 params = {
        "location":'cf6707e3-f0ae-4040-a184-737b21a4bbd1',
         "dateAdded":'ge:11/23/2020'}
url = requests.get('https://api2.com/api/assets',auth=('api2', '123456'), params=params)
r = json.loads(url.content)
r['items']
```

The JSON payload looks like this

```
[{'id': '064ca857-3783-460e-a7a2-245e054dcbe3',
  'name': 'Apple Laptop 1',
  'model': {'id': '50f5993e-2abf-49c8-86e0-8743dd58db6f',
   'name': 'MacBook Pro'},
  'manufacturer': {'id': 'f56244e2-76e3-46da-97dd-f72f92ca0779',
   'name': 'APPLE'},
  'room': {'id': '700ff2dc-0118-46c6-936a-01f0fa88c620',
   'name': 'Storage Room 1',
   'thirdPartyId': ''},
  'location': {'id': 'cf6707e3-f0ae-4040-a184-737b21a4bbd1',
   'name': 'Iron Mountain',
   'thirdPartyId': ''},
  'position': 'NonMounted',
  'containerAsset': {'id': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
   'name': None},
  'baseAsset': {'id': '064ca857-3783-460e-a7a2-245e054dcbe3',
   'name': 'Apple Laptop 1'},
  'description': None,
  'status': {'id': 'df9906d8-2856-45e3-9cba-bd7a1ac4971f',
   'name': 'Production'},
  'serialNumber': '5QBYGKUI06',
  'tagNumber': None,
  'alternateTagNumber': None,
  'verificationStatus': {'id': 'cb3560a9-eef5-47b9-b033-394d3a09db18',
   'name': 'Verified'},
  'requiresRFID': False,
  'requiresHangTag': False,
  'bottomPosition': 0.0,
  'leftPosition': 0.0,
  'rackPosition': 'Front',
  'labelX': None,
  'labelY': None,
  'verifyNameInRear': False,
  'verifySerialNumberInRear': False,
  'verifyBarcodeInRear': False,
  'isNonDataCenter': False,
  'rotate': False,
  'customer': {'id': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 'name': None},
  'thirdPartyId': '',
  'temperature': None,
  'dateLastScanned': None,
  'placement': 'Floor',
  'lastScannedLabelX': None,
  'lastScannedLabelY': None,
  'userDefinedValues': [{'userDefinedKeyId': '79e77a1e-4030-4308-a8ff-9caf40c04fbd',
    'userDefinedKeyName': 'Longitude ',
    'value': '-75.208917'},
   {'userDefinedKeyId': '72c8056e-9b7d-40ac-9270-9f5929097e82',
    'userDefinedKeyName': 'Address',
    'value': '800 Laurel Rd, New York ,NY 19050, USA'},
   {'userDefinedKeyId': '31aeeb91-daef-4364-8dd6-b0e3436d6a51',
    'userDefinedKeyName': 'Battery Level',
    'value': '67'},
   {'userDefinedKeyId': '22b7ce4f-7d3d-4282-9ecb-e8ec2238acf2',
    'userDefinedKeyName': 'Latitude',
    'value': '35.932179'}]}
```

The documentation provided by API 2 tells me they only support PUT for updates as of right now but I would also want to know how I would do this using PATCH as it will be available in the future. So the data payload that I need to successful  PUT is this

```
payload = {'id': '064ca857-3783-460e-a7a2-245e054dcbe3',
 'name': 'Apple Laptop 1',
 'model': {'id': '50f5993e-2abf-49c8-86e0-8743dd58db6f',
  'name': 'MacBook Pro'},
 'manufacturer': {'id': 'f56244e2-76e3-46da-97dd-f72f92ca0779',
  'name': 'APPLE'},
 'room': {'id': '700ff2dc-0118-46c6-936a-01f0fa88c620',
  'name': 'Storage Room 1',
  'thirdPartyId': ''},
 'status': {'id': 'df9906d8-2856-45e3-9cba-bd7a1ac4971f',
  'name': 'Production'},
 'serialNumber': '5QBYGKUI06',
 'verificationStatus': {'id': 'cb3560a9-eef5-47b9-b033-394d3a09db18',
  'name': 'Verified'},
 'requiresRFID': 'False',
 'requiresHangTag': 'False',
 'userDefinedValues': [{'userDefinedKeyId': '79e77a1e-4030-4308-a8ff-9caf40c04fbd',
   'userDefinedKeyName': 'Longitude ',
   'value': '-75.248920'},
  {'userDefinedKeyId': '72c8056e-9b7d-40ac-9270-9f5929097e82',
   'userDefinedKeyName': 'Address',
   'value': '801 Laurel Rd, New York, Ny 192250, USA'},
  {'userDefinedKeyId': '31aeeb91-daef-4364-8dd6-b0e3436d6a51',
   'userDefinedKeyName': 'Battery Level',
   'value': '67'},
  {'userDefinedKeyId': '22b7ce4f-7d3d-4282-9ecb-e8ec2238acf2',
   'userDefinedKeyName': 'Latitude',
   'value': '29.782177'}]}
```

So apart of this is figuring out how I can query the json data portions that I need for the update

I am able to update the information using this line

```
requests.put('https://api2.com/api/assets/064ca857-3783-460e-a7a2-245e054dcbe3',auth=('API2', '123456'), data=json.dumps(payload))
```

but I need for it to dynamically update so I don't think the hard coded id parameter in the line will be efficient in a automation/efficiency standpoint. If anybody has any ideas, resources to point me in the right direction to know more about this process (I don't really know what it is even called) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, but if you want to pull information nested in the responses you can do this.

Serial number from API 1

```
r['device']['serial_no']
```

Serial number for API 2

```
either r[0]['serialNumber'] or r['items'][0]['serialNumber'] depending on what you are showing
```

To modify the payload serial number, for example

```
payload['serialNumber'] = '123456abcdef'
```

Comment: This helps, I am trying to  update the Location, Latitude, Address, Battery Status information from API 2 with that same information from API 1, by matching them on serial number